# GRASS problem - r.viewshed.cva addon

Tags: grass-gis, extensions

I'm a very beginner at GRASS. I'm using GRASS 7.0 and I tried to install r.vieshed.cva extension. When installed, if I type it in the command line, it appears

> "r.viewshed.cva" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file

Could someone help me?

Comment: How did you install the extension and which operating system do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I probably have found the error and updated the command in the GRASS GIS Addons repository. Within 24 hours (i.e. tomorrow), the updated module will be online available:

> g.extension r.viewshed.cva